# prevent ReactJs component sent from rendering

Tags: reactjs, render, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I use the component that receives texts typed by the client, but clients happen to type in codes (such as an iframe), and dangerouslySetInnerHTML lets it render!
I would like it to show the code on screen (and I already tried to convert it to a string etc.) but not to render it.

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message }}></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the message to be dom, then why use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in the first place?

```html
<p>{message}</p>
```

Comment: This worked quite well in my context! Thank you!

Comment: @c_mariana mark the question as accepted if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

use dompurify, useful for these scenarios, but i am not really sure how you are not able render this, posting a code snippet would help.

Comment: DOMPurify really solves a number of contexts, even possible attacks, but when you click it, it simply returns what it cleaned and identified it as wrong, it returns blank (" "), which for me that needs to be shown on screen ended up not working :(

Comment: what challenge are you facing, could you post a snippet?